# Configuring an AWS E2 proxy for SSH-tunnelling your web browser

Tags: ssh-tunneling, proxy, aws

A web browser usually connects to the Internet directly. Sometimes that's undesirable. On such occasions, routing traffic via another system is preferable.

VPNs achieve the desired result, but typically require monthly subscriptions. SSH-tunnels offer an alternative solution. Given AWS E2 can serve as a termination point, billing can be based on usage, rather than a standing charge, which seems fairer.

How do I configure an AWS E2 instance, a computer and a browser for SSH tunneling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AWS's control panel to launch an instance (having selected your prefered region):

1. Select Ubuntu OS Image
2. Create a key pair (and download)
3. Check *network settings* for selection of *create security group* and *allow SSH traffic from: Anywhere*
4. Launch your instance

Next *connect to your instance*, select *SSH client*, and follow instructions to connect, e.g.,

5. `mv ~/Downloads/keypair.pem .`
6. `chmod 400 keypair.pem`
7. copy, paste, and execute the ssh command, something like: `ssh -i "keypair.pem" ubuntu@ec2-abc.def.compute.amazonaws.com`

Update your instance (rebooting, `sudo reboot`, if required), i.e.,

8. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Install a proxy (and disconnect), e.g.,

9. `sudo apt install tinyproxy && exit`

You're now ready to tunnel your browser's web connection over E2, using the proxy's default settings (listening on 127.0.0.1:8888):

10. `ssh -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8888 -i "keypair.pem" ubuntu@ec2-abc.def.compute.amazonaws.com`

Instruct your browser to proxy http(s) via localhost on port 8888, and you're away! (To check, lookup your IP geolocation online.)

Comment: You don't need tinyproxy for this. OpenSSH has a perfectly fine SOCKS proxy implementation built-in (`ssh -D <port> ...`)